# ValidationMessage already triggered when loading the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I load a view all the validation messages are already triggered, so it won't stop me from submitting to POST if leave all the values as null

View (shortened):

```
    @model  MyProject.ViewModel.VentasViewModel

   @{
    Layout = null;
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="row">

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NombreCliente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", style = "color:black" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NombreCliente, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "E.j. Juan", style = "width:350px" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NombreCliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
           <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
     }
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Create(VentasViewModel newProduct)
        {
            var details = db.DetallesVentaTMPs.ToList();
            newProduct.DetallesVentas2 = details;
            ViewBag.LocalidadId = new SelectList(db.Localidads, "LocalidadId", "Name");       
            return View(newProduct);
        }
```

VentasViewModel(shortened too):

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModel
{
    public class VentasViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo requerido")] //<-This what I get
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El campo desbe estar entre {2} y 
        {1} caracteres", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        public string NombreCliente { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is required")]
        [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You must select a {0}")]
        [Display(Name = "Localidad")]
        public int LocalidadId { get; set; }

   public Localidad Localidad { get; set; }

   public List<DetallesVentaTMP> DetallesVentas2 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I really have no clue what could be causing this. Any hint?

Comment: Please provide `VentasViewModel` code

Comment: You're right @RajdeepDebnath, done.

Comment: You included unobtrusive libraries?

Comment: I don't know what's that, but I have some other views in which I have no issues like this

Comment: Are you loading some `jquery` javascripts ion the other view (which is working)?

Comment: Yes I am, but I removed them and debugged and the issue persists @RajdeepDebnath

Comment: You can enable client side validation which will prevent from the form being submitted unless all validation error goes away.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221976/discussion-between-rajdeep-debnath-and-bautista-gonzalez-carpani).

Comment: I added it the steps to answer, let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Would you come to the chat room for a sec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to include below 3 files in your `_layout.cshtml` file or better way is to put them in `BundleConfig.cs` file. This will work based on data annotation set in your model class. This will enable asp.net mvc to fire client side validation without server side roudtrip.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
}
```

You can also enable/disable it from web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> //enabled, set 'false' to disable
  </appSettings>
```